# JQuery giving 403 forbidden error in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I'm doing some calculation to check whether user entered valid amount or not. I'm calling JQuery method on keyup event of text field. As this request will be sent again and again on keyup, I have created csrf token inside the form and used its generated value in a JQuery method. Every time this is called, it gives me the error "403 Forbidden". Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my html:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
                             <?php 
                                                    $hash_name=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();
                        $hash_value=$this->security->get_csrf_hash();
                        ?>
                        <input type="text" id="hash_value" value="<?php echo $hash_value;?>" style="display: none" />                           
                              <h3>Transfer to cash wallet</h3>
                              <div class="form-group form-animate-text" style="margin-top:40px !important;">
                                <input type="text" class="form-text" name="amount" id="ent_amount" onkeyup="check_balance(this.value)" required>
                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                <label>Amount to transfer</label>
                              </div>                                 
                              <h5 id="amount_over"></h5>                                  
                              <input type='button' class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-t-n-xs" onclick="submitCash()" id='myBtn' value="Transfer" />
                            </form>
```

Here is my JQuery method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function check_balance(str){

    $(document).ready(function(){   

        var hash_value=$("#hash_value").val();

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "Users/check_earning", 
             data: {amount: str, csrf_snt_token: hash_value},
             dataType: "text",  
             cache:false,
             success: 
                  function(data){
                   if(data==200){

                   }
                  else{

                    $('#amount_over').html('* Transfer amount is greater than total balance'); 

                    }


                  }
              });
         return false;

     });   


}
     </script>
```

here is my controller function

```
public function check_earning(){

        $entered_amount=$this->input->post('amount');                   
        $total_earnings=500;           
        if($entered_amount>$total_earnings){

            echo "error";
        }
        else{

            echo "200";
        }

    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: a word of advice, you would want to change the approach to form validation from a server validation to a javascript/frontend validation. Making requests on every keyup from multiple users on a platform is bound to increase the load on the backend system causing it to lock and hang at some point. Don't get me wrong server validation is important, but not in this manner.

Comment: @ShalomSam thank you for your advice, I'll consider your recommendations :) but right now if I'll eliminate onkeyup event and simple call JQuery method on button click then It'll show again the same error.

Comment: You should confirm if the correct csrf token value exists in the form and compare what value is being compared against when the post request is sent to the server. And if they match. Also check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was to get the fresh generated token. i was making multiple ajax request on this page. After every request to controller codeigniter generates new CSRF token and i was sending the same token again and again. I used cookie to get the fresh CSRF token because Codeigniter stores every fresh CSRF token in the cookie. 
i removed these lines from the form

```
$hash_name=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();
$hash_value=$this->security->get_csrf_hash();
<input type="text" id="hash_value" value="<?php echo $hash_value;?>" style="display: none" />
```

After removing it, i get fresh token from cookie by using javascript. here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function get_cookie(ck) {    
    var name = ck + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';'); 
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
       var c = ca[i];
       while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
       if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
   }
   return "";   
}

function check_balance(str){

    var csrf_ck=get_cookie('csrf_cookie_snt');
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo site_url("users/check_earning"); ?>', 
    data: {amount: str, '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':csrf_ck},
    dataType: "text",  
    cache:false,
    success: 
         function(data){
          if(data=='200'){

          }
         else{

           $('#amount_over').html('* Transfer amount is greater than total balance'); 

           }


         }
     });

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Can you test this?**

```
function check_balance(str){
        var hash_value = $("#hash_value").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('users/check_earning'); ?>", //changes
            data: ({amount: str, csrf_snt_token: hash_value}), //changes
            dataType: 'json',  
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){
                if(data.status == 0){

                }else{
                    $('#amount_over').html('* Transfer amount is greater than total balance'); 
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

**controller:**

```
public function check_earning() {
        $entered_amount = $this->input->post('amount');
        $total_earnings = 500;
        if ($entered_amount > $total_earnings) {
            $response_array['status'] = 1;
        } else {
            $response_array['status'] = 0;
        }
        echo json_encode($response_array);
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: please check now

Comment: i tested it brother, no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can try csrf token direct in JS instead from HTML

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '<?php echo site_url("users/check_earning"); ?>', 
         data: {amount: str, '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'},
         cache:false,
         success: 
              function(data){
               if(data=='200'){

               }
              else{

                $('#amount_over').html('* Transfer amount is greater than total balance'); 

                }


              }
          });
```

Notice several changes there. Also dont forget to enable `csrf_protection` to `TRUE` in `config/config.php`

Comment: csrf_protection is enabled and i tried the same before using csrf token inside form but not working

Answer (score 0):

I think the `dataType: "text"` is causing the issue here. Try a value of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `application/json`, depending on the dataType expected on the backend. Like so -

```
          $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "users/check_earning", 
             data: {amount: str, csrf_snt_token: hash_value},
             dataType: "application/json",  
             cache:false,
             success: 
                  function(data){
                   if(data==200){

                   }
                  else{

                    $('#amount_over').html('* Transfer amount is greater than total balance'); 

                    }


                  }
              });
```

PS: `User` needs to be `user` in the endpoint.

Comment: I'll be happy to look at it if you can host it up on Heroku and give me access.

Comment: i actually fixed it by using cookie. Thank you for you response, it is very much appreciated :)